# Slow magento product save CE 1.6

Tags: admin, multistore, magento-1.6, performance, mysql-config

I have a magento CE 1.6 store, with ~ 22.000 products, and the product save in the admin panel takes about 70 secs.

The product attributes index was set to manual.
Flat tables are enabled.
Zend cache is enabled.
Mysql query cache is enabled, with 128M buffer size.
The log is cleaned from database, and its size is over 1.5 GB
The var/reports folder is empty.
The system.log, and the exception.log is empty.
The product attributes is separeted in some attribute sets.
There is no unused products.
The store is running on a shared server...There are 6 stores, in the system.

Can anybody help to me? I googled so many time, with no results...

Thanks

Comment: What are the specifications of the shared server?

Comment: If by shared server, you mean shared hosting plan, then I wonder how could you went up to 22000 products. With such a large catalog, Each magento store would require a dedicated server for itself.

Comment: Yes, this is on a shared hosting

Comment: Is this a recently created magento store? Did you always have this issue? Did you recently add more products or stores?

Comment: This shop running over 2 years, and the system is getting slower day by day

Answer (score 1):

One of the best option for you is to switch on magento-specific hosting and enable profiler to see if some extension does time consuming operation on product save.